# Patterns to show content in a React and AWS website

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

Sorry about the "stupid" title, but I don't really know how to explain this.

I want to have a webpage on my site (built in `React`), that will show the release notes for each version of my site/product. I can hardcode the content of the release notes in the page, but I want to do something that allows me not to have to recompile my site just to change content.

My site is hosted in `AWS`, so I was thinking if there are any patterns to store the content of the page in an `S3` bucket as a text file, or as an entry in `DynamoDB`.

Does this make sense?

These are things I remember, but I would like to ask how "you" have done this in the past.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could really use either S3 or DynamoDB, though S3 ends up being more favorable for a few reasons.

For S3, the general pattern would be to store your formatted release notes as an HTML file (or multiple files) as S3 objects and have your site make AJAX requests to the S3 object(s) and load the HTML stored there as your formatted release notes.

Benefits:

- You can make the request client-side and asynchronous via AJAX, so the rest of the page load time isn't negatively impacted.
- If you want to change the formatting of the release notes, you can do so by just changing the S3 object. No site recompilation required.
- S3 is cheap.

If you were to use DynamoDB, you would have to request the contents server-side and format them server-side (the format would not be changeable without site recompilation). You get 25 read capacity units for free, but if your site sees a lot of traffic, you could end up paying much more than you would with S3.

Comment: Thanks Tom. It goes along the lines of what I was thinking as well.